# Switch Statement - Nested Functions - C++

Tags: c++, function, nested, switch-statement

I want to have a function called "userPrompt" andit ask for the user to enter a value for integer named "choose" so after that I would be able to use switch statement.

But It dosen't work it says: "choose" undeclared.

I suppose it would start the main function first,and inside of it the first command would be initializing the userPrompt func. then thanks to userPrompt I would have a choose value so that the switch would work.

So what is the problem with this code?

How can I use nested functions?(I hope it is called like that)

Is my code's order wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
userPrompt(){

    int choose;

    cout << " Please Choose An Option : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 1 to Add new grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 2 to Calculate the average grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 3 to Calculate the total grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 4 to Exit : " << endl;    

    cin >> choose;

}

    int main()
    {

        userPrompt();

        switch(choose){

        case 1
            getGrade();
            userPrompt();
            break;

        case 2

            int average;
            getGrade();   

            average = total/counter;

            cout << average; 

            break;     

        case 3

            getGrade();
            cout << total;
            break;

        case 4

            cout << "Thanks for Trying" << endl;

            return 0;

            system("pause");

            break;

        default

            cout << "Please Choose A Valid Option ! : " << endl;
            validOption();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `choose` is declared only locally in `userPrompt()` you need a `return` statement or output parameter, to pass the value to another variable inside `main()`. There are many more syntactical errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm new at C++ also new at programming.It'll get better I hope :)

I will fix it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `colon` in your `case` and also you need to `return choose`.

```
case 1:
```

Try this:

```
int userPrompt(){

int choose;

cout << " Please Choose An Option : " << endl;
cout << " Type 1 to Add new grades : " << endl;
cout << " Type 2 to Calculate the average grades : " << endl;
cout << " Type 3 to Calculate the total grades : " << endl;
cout << " Type 4 to Exit : " << endl;    

cin >> choose;
return choose;
}
int main()
{

    int choose = userPrompt();

    switch(choose){

    case 1:
        getGrade();
        userPrompt();
        break;

    case 2:

        int average;
        getGrade();   

        average = total/counter;

        cout << average; 

        break;     

    case 3:

        getGrade();
        cout << total;
        break;

    case 4:

        cout << "Thanks for Trying" << endl;

        return 0;

        system("pause");

        break;

    default:

        cout << "Please Choose A Valid Option ! : " << endl;
        validOption();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it fixed my problem.Altough I have my new problems now I know how to fix them for this situation thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses "scope" which sort of translates into the "visibility" of variables. The "choose" variable of your userPrompt() function is only "visible" (within reach) inside the scope of the userPrompt() function.

So you could declare the userPrompt() function as

```
int userPrompt() // Returns the user choice
{
    ... // your existing code here
    return choose;
}
```

Then inside main() you would do something like:

```
int main()
{
  int choice = userPrompt();
  switch(choice)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your technical explanation , I'll keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this :

```
int userPrompt(){  //--> changed into a function returning the choice

    int choose;

    cout << " Please Choose An Option : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 1 to Add new grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 2 to Calculate the average grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 3 to Calculate the total grades : " << endl;
    cout << " Type 4 to Exit : " << endl;    

    cin >> choose;
    return choose;
}

int main()
{
    //--> declare choose in main and assign a value using the function call
    int choose = userPrompt(); 

    switch(choose){

    case 1:
        getGrade();
        userPrompt();
        break;

    case 2:

        int average;
        getGrade();   

        average = total/counter;

        cout << average; 

        break;     

    case 3:

        getGrade();
        cout << total;
        break;

    case 4:

        cout << "Thanks for Trying" << endl;

        return 0;

        system("pause");

        break;

    default

        cout << "Please Choose A Valid Option ! : " << endl;
        validOption();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this way too.It look like the same with the previous code sent by Rahul Tripathi :)

Comment: It is the same, we posted our code at the same time. But do me a favor and upvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake. put colon in cases `case 1:` like that

`intialize the choose first and try it.

`int choose = o;`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ every function has a return type. This means that it will return something or return void (i.e, return nothing). In your program `userPrompt` has no return type neither void or any other return type hence this part is the first error in your program.
The next error is that after every case label in the **switch** statement that label must be followed by a colon **':'**